# Python script to control GPIO

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I have a very small python script to control GPIOs:

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python gpio-test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
try:
   from time import sleep
   import os
   import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
   GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT)
   GPIO.output(6,True)              
   while True:   
      sleep(1);
finally:
   GPIO.cleanup()
```

The script does not take any effect with the GPIO6 where I have a led.

I've made another java program using the library pi4j and it works fine turning the led ON for 5 seconds:

```
package test;

import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinDigitalOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;

public class GPIOTest {

    static final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();;
    static final GpioPinDigitalOutput[] output = new GpioPinDigitalOutput[15];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        output[6] = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_06, "output6",PinState.LOW);
        output[6].setState(PinState.HIGH);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        output[0].setState(PinState.LOW);
        gpio.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gpio6 is only available on a Rev.3 board, a model B+.

See http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#General_Purpose_Input.2FOutput_.28GPIO.29 and use the proper Broadcom number for the gpio which is connected to your LED.

Comment: mm... OK, Thanks Joan !! using GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT) it works.

I see that the mapping using p4j: http://pi4j.com/images/gpio-control-example.png
is different than the mapping using Python http://elinux.org/images/2/2a/GPIOs.png